# VBA - Can anyone explain why I get object errors with Cells()?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

All, I am having extreme trouble understanding why I am getting object errors. Every time I read something, I think I have it figured out, and when I try to implement I get an error.  The particular code I am working with right now is:

```
'Set station cell value
iRow = rEmptyStation.Row
iColumn = rEmptyStation.Column
Cells(iRow - 1, iColumn).Copy
Range(Cells(iRow, iColumn), Cells(iRow, iColumn)).Select
Selection.Paste
rEmptyStation.Value = sStation
```

`iRow` and `iColumn` are of type long, `rEmptyStation` is a range, and `sStation` is a string.  All I'm trying to do is copy the cell above the cell in question, paste it to the cell in question (for it's formatting), and then set the cell in question equal to a string.

It gives me an object error on the line where I have `[junk].Select`.  In place of `[junk]`, I have tried putting `Cells(iRow, iColumn)`, I have tried using a `With Worksheets(1)` and `.Cells(iRow, iColumn)` statement, and I've also tried using `.Cells()` and `.Range()` in the `With` statement.

Can ANYONE explain to me how to get this to work, and how to choose the right code in every situation????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was switching my code to the following:

```
'Set station cell value
iRow = rEmptyStation.Row
iColumn = rEmptyStation.Column
Cells(iRow - 1, iColumn).Copy
Cells(iRow, iColumn).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
rEmptyStation.Value = sStation
```

Now, I don't know why, but when I have the code as the following, I get the object error (at the `Selection.Paste` line):

```
'Set station cell value
iRow = rEmptyStation.Row
iColumn = rEmptyStation.Column
Cells(iRow - 1, iColumn).Copy
Cells(iRow, iColumn).Select
Selection.Paste
rEmptyStation.Value = sStation
```

Here is [a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qb6xolaiyqbc6y/Master%20E85%20Tracker.xlsm) to my project in its entirety.  If anyone can figure that out, that'd be great (the code after this snippet in question is NOT TESTED!).

Answer (score 2):

I can't really tell why it's not working because i can't see your data
Possible reason is if value of `iRow` is 1.
Excel cannot evaluate `Cells(0,iColumn)`.

You can try this:

```
If iRow <> 1 Then: _
Cells(iRow - 1, iColumn).Copy Cells(iRow, iColumn) '~~> Direct copy
rEmptyStation.Value = sStation
```

or if you just want to copy formats of the `Cell` above `rEmptyStation` then:

```
If rEmptyStation.Row <> 1 Then
    rEmptyStation(-1).Copy
    rEmptyStation.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats '~~> Direct copy and paste formats
    rEmptyStation.Value = sStation
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe add a test for `rEmptyStation Is Nothing` in case it's not set.  This is most likely the answer, shame the OP hasn't provided feedback.

Comment: When my code runs, iRow and iColumn are not 1 or 0.  Also, in code above I have `If rEmptyStation Is Nothing Then`, so it's not that either.  As of right now, my code produces iRow and iColumn as 6 and 13, respectively.  I am going to record a macro right now to see if it gives me something, but since I am referring to rows and columns found from a range, I don't know if it will be useful.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Also, I am working on this in my spare time at home, so I'm not going to be super dedicated to it.

Answer (score 0):

This following code works for me:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sStation As String
    Dim rEmptyStation As Range
    Dim selectedCell As Range
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iColumn As Integer

    sStation = "Test"
    Set rEmptyStation = Range("A2")

    'Set station cell value
    iRow = rEmptyStation.Row
    iColumn = rEmptyStation.Column
    Cells(iRow - 1, iColumn).Copy
    Set selectedCell = Range(Cells(iRow, iColumn), Cells(iRow, iColumn))
    selectedCell.PasteSpecial
    rEmptyStation.Value = sStation

End Sub
```

If you put the string 'Original' in A1, it is copied into cell A2, then the text in A2 is replaced with 'Test'.